# Can anyone tell me how this works?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
(function(ng, app){
    app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.config(function($provide) {
        $provide.constant('town', 'Burlington');
    });

    app.constant('name', 'Rob F.');

    app.controller('MainCtrl', [
        'name', 'town',
        function MainCtrl(name, town) {
            this.getName = function() {
                return name;
            };

            this.getTown = function() {
                return town;
            };
        }
    ]);
}(angular));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/founddrama/RvXn3/

I see that we are passing `angular` as a argument, but the IIFE collects `ng, app`. Can anyone tell me what is `ng, app` here? I don't see `ng` used any where?

Comment: This is a poorly written code that's why

Answer (score 1):

And you dont have to use these arguments. You can run this code without the parameters. Then the `app` variable will be declared implicitly.s No need to use these Parameters :)

Comment: to add : angular inside the function is using angular as global variable.